# Silverlight to MVC to WP7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, windows-phone-7

We have been developing a silverlight app for the last couple of years. We have a large library base and much of it is reused on the ASP.Net MVC version which we have been developing for a month or so. So I created an MVC app and pretty much added the libraries from the Silverlight server app.

I would like to do a demo for the WP7 version of our app and was wondering what is the best way to reuse the libraries we already have? I was told that I could share files but with such a large library based, I do not want to go that way.

Would it be possible to expose the MVC app via WCF and then get access to the data in WP7 where I can then all the XAML views?

I do not have any experience on the architecture of WP7.

TIA
JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is have the MVC app expose the data via a Controller (possibly returning it as json) which would be your "api".

WP7 would just need to make a web request to the api you've already made. [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) should make this quite easy.

This way you wouldn't need to use WCF.

Hope this helps.
Tony

Comment: Thanks that is interesting. Would I have to create new controller or reuse the existing ones but now they return JSON? If the latter is the way to go, that also means I have to change my jquery/HTML5 UI to handle the JSON responses fro my existing MVC app?

Comment: Personally I create a new controller (ApiController). Instead of returning this.View(yourModelHere) you would return this.JSON(yourModelHere)

Comment: Depending on your timelines, you might want to check out the [WCF Web APIs](http://wcf.codeplex.com/) as they provide WP7 support for executing web requests and parsing the response to a particular type.

Comment: @Richard: You mentioned timelines, is it the learning curve that is an issue? I have no experience in WCF and maybe it is a good time to look at this now.

Comment: @Richard: I already have an mvc app and silverlight app, can I build on top of these or would I have to create a new app (which would be more work)?

Comment: @Richard: After more reading, wcf web api is not ready yet (hence the timeline). Also new changes may break existing code. I think for now I will go down the mvc/json route and once I have built up my knowledge on wcf, I will look at wcf web api. Thanks.